# Changing Visual Studio XML Summary Blocks VB.NET v C# Display

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I work with both vb.net and c# in Visual Studio 2010, and something which annoys the hell out of me is that XML Summary blocks display differently between vb.net and c#

Opened summary blocks look like this

VB

```
''' <summary>
''' This is the summary of what the method does
''' </summary>
```

C#

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the summary of what the method does
/// </summary>
```

Collapsed summary blocks look like this

VB

```
This is the summary of what the method does
```

C#

```
/// <summary> ...
```

In VB this is great, you get to see the summary! However in C# having many `/// <summary> ...` on the page is an eyesore.

Is there are way to change the way that C# displays this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there are way to change the way that C# displays this in Visual Studio?

Yes, there is, but not that easy. DevExpress rewrites the UI a lot - but it is tricky and heavy programming.

Without that - no, i do no think so.

Comment: darn. not the answer I was hoping for! maybe I need to look into the `tricky and heavy programming` part and sell a plugin :) Thanks for the speedy answer